# Connection from Lambda to Aurora database fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've set up an Aurora PostgreSQL compatible database. I can connect to the database via the public address but I'm not able to connect via a Lambda function which is placed in the same VPC.

This is just a test environment and the security settings are weak. In the network settings I tried to use "no VPC" and I tried my default VPC where the database and the lambda are placed. But this doesn't make a difference.

This is my nodejs code to create a simple Select statement:

```
var params = {
  awsSecretStoreArn: '{mySecurityARN}',
  dbClusterOrInstanceArn: 'myDB-ARN', 
  sqlStatements: 'SELECT * FROM userrole',
  database: 'test',
  schema: 'user'
};

const aurora = new AWS.RDSDataService();

let userrightData = await aurora.executeSql(params).promise();
```

When I start my test in the AWS GUI I get following errors:

```
  "errorType": "UnknownEndpoint",
  "errorMessage": "Inaccessible host: `rds-data.eu-central- 1.amazonaws.com'. This service may not be available in the `eu-central-1' region.",
  "trace": [
  "UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: `rds-data.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com'. This service may not be available in the `eu-central-1' region.",
```

I've already checked the [tutorial of Amazon](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-rds-tutorial.html) but I can't find a point I did't try.

Comment: What are the security group rules assigned to the RDS instance?

Comment: Any idea why the first error message says "rds-data.eu-central- 1" with a space between the hyphen and the 1?

Comment: Just a copy/paste error. The space doesn't appear in the 'real' error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message *"This service may not be available in the `eu-central-1' region."* is absolutely right because in eu-central-1 an Aurora Serverless database is not available.

I configured an Aurora Postgres and not an **Aurora Serverless** DB.

"*AWS.RDSDataService()*", what I wanted to use to connect to the RDB, is only available in relation to an Aurora Serverless instance. It's described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/RDSDataService.html.

This is the reason why this error message appeared.